# How to add Totals in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the totals of each month as of YTD (Years to date) Can someone please help me figure out how to integrate this in my query? thank you This is what I have so far.

```
DECLARE @Year int    
set @Year = 2013    
select  a.first_name,  a.last_name 
, COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(b.Funded_date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) January
, COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(b.Funded_date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) February
, COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(b.Funded_date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) March
, COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(b.Funded_date) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) April
From tContact a Join tContract b ON a.contact_id = b.contract_id
Group by a.first_name,   a.last_name
```

Comment: "a.contact_id = b.contract_id" Should be "a.contact_id = b.contact_id" And you didn't use @Year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Count(*) As Total function. I'm sure this will help you

```
SELECT MONTH(b.Funded_date) AS 'MonthNum',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Total'
FROM Table AS b
WHERE YEAR(b.Funded_date) = 2014
GROUP BY MONTH(b.Funded_date)
```

Comment: @user3657264 not only is this an exact copy of an answer given the day you posted your question it does not do what you describe in your question. You say you want totals year-to-date by month which is NOT what this does. This is just totals for a month...

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example of how you could count up rows that fall under a certain month.

```
SELECT MONTH(b.Funded_date) AS 'MonthNum',
       COUNT(*) AS 'Total'
FROM Table AS b
WHERE YEAR(b.Funded_date) = 2014
GROUP BY MONTH(b.Funded_date)
```

Hopefully this will help you with your query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I tried to do here is create an upper bound record for each month in `tContract` then join that back into the query you already had. It is joined on dates that are between the beginning of the year and the current month.

```
DECLARE @Year int    
set @Year = 2013
select Ms.thismonth, count(B.thing_You_are_Totalling) from (
    select thisMonth = dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,Funded_date),0)
    from tContract
    where moid = 2005405
    and year(Funded_date) = @Year
    group by dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,Funded_date),0)
) Ms

inner join (select * from tContact a inner join tContract ON a.contact_id = tContract.contract_id)  B 
    on B.Funded_date >=dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,B.Funded_date),0) -- beginning of year
            and B.Funded_date <= Ms.thisMonth  -- this month
where year(B.Funded_date) = @Year          -- restrict to only this year
    group by thisMonth, first_name,   last_name
```

I don't have your full table definition so there might be some issues (maybe a SqlFiddle is in order)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for.

```
select  a.first_name,  a.last_name 
, COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(b.Funded_date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) January
, COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(b.Funded_date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) February
, COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(b.Funded_date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) March
, COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(b.Funded_date) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) April
, COUNT(*) TotalCount
, SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(b.Funded_date) = 1 THEN Amount ELSE NULL END) JanuaryAmount
, SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(b.Funded_date) = 2 THEN Amount ELSE NULL END) FebruaryAmount
, SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(b.Funded_date) = 3 THEN Amount ELSE NULL END) MarchAmount
, SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(b.Funded_date) = 4 THEN Amount ELSE NULL END) AprilAmount

From tContact a Join tContract b ON a.contact_id = b.contact_id
WHERE YEAR(b.Funded_date) = @Year
Group by a.first_name,   a.last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
declare @year int = 2013

select a.first_name
       , a.last_name 
       , month(b.Funded_date) [Month]
       , datename(month, dateadd(month, month(date_of_birth_dt), - 1)) [MonthName]
       , count(month(b.Funded_date)) [Total]
  from tContact a 
 where a.[Year] = @year
 group by a.first_name, a.last_name, month(b.Funded_date)
```

It returns the total of each Month for the year 2013. `a.[Year]` might not the the name of the field that you have so adjust accordingly. Also, `[Month]` returns numeric value for month.